# Hide path in google

Tags: html, google-chrome

In my html code I made a button to one of my other html codes. But I want to hide the path in browser. Is that possible with html?

Now is it this.

```
file:///C:/Users/Matteo/Desktop/programs/html/Matteo.html
```

And I want to change it to this.

```
Matteo.html
```

Comment: you mean you want to hide it in the navigation bar of the browser? Like this: https://postimg.cc/K35qCkY6 ? Or hide it in the href attribute of your buttons?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The browser has to resolve the relative URL into an absolute URL in order to know which path to ask for and which server to ask for it.

Of course, it will only resolve to a `file:` scheme URL if it is a *local* file that isn't public facing in the first place. So there is no need to be concerned about leaking information about the structure of your personal hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly...

You can use relative URIs if you know the directory structure for example, if the file `Matteo.html` is in the same directory as the currently opened file, you can replace `file:///C:/Users/Matteo/Desktop/programs/html/Matteo.html` with just `Matteo.html`. If that file is opened and you want to open `file:///C:/Users/Matteo/Desktop/programs/a/b/c.html`, you can replace that with `../a/b/c`.